# Complex Analysis 2.1.2 - 1 If g(w) and f(z) are analytic functions, show that g(f(z)) is also analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, analytic-functions

Complex Analysis 2.1.2 - 1

> If $g(w)$ and $f(z)$ are analytic functions, show that $g(f(z))$ is also analytic.

Comment: What have you tried? Please update your question with ideas or content of your own work. I provided a hint below to get you started in at least one of a couple possible directions.

Comment: The issue of the composition being analytic requires some context for the domains on which the functions $f,g$ are defined.  If you assume analytic in the whole complex plane (entire functions), do you have a way to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the Cauchy Riemann equations.
Another way :
$\lim\limits_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(z_{0}))}{z-z_0}=\lim\limits_{z \to z_{0}} \frac{g(f(z))-g(f(0))}{f(z)-f(0)} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$. It is not hard to see that this limit is $g'(f(z_0))f'(z_0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

One of the definitions of $f$ being analytic is that is satisfies the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function). Assuming both $g,f$ analytic, can you plug $g(f(z))$ into the Cauchy-Riemann equations and see what happens?